# Android launch application cross profile

Tags: android, mdm

I have an Android app in the Personal Profile App A. I know there is an app installed in Work Profile, not my app, App B.

Is it possible to launch App B from App A even if there is user approval or some minimal user intervention needed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible to launch App B in work profile from App A in personal profile.

- App A in personal profile can launch a custom share intent which can be handled by the App B in work profile
- By default , most intents do not cross from one profile to the another. The profile IT admin imposes restrictions on which intents are allowed to cross to the other profiles.
- The application [Android BasicManagedProfile Sample](https://github.com/android/enterprise-samples/tree/main/BasicManagedProfile#readme) can be setup as an IT profile admin to understand and control intent forwarding between profiles.
- In general intents are handled on the same profile where those are fired from . Make sure there's no handler for the intent fired from App A on the personal profile AND the admin restrictions on the work profile allow intents to cross the profile boundaries.

Further reading [Prevent failed intents](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#prevent_failed_intents) , [Work profiles](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles) on developers.android.com

Comment: The app I am trying to launch in work profile is VMware's MDM Hub app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airwatch.androidagent&hl=en_US&gl=US

It is installed first first on personal profile and once activated with organization, it creates a work profile and installs itself in work profile, same package name. 
I want to launch the Hub app in the work profile but when I startActivity using intent from my app it opens instance on personal profile that has no info. If I uninstall it from personal profile, the startActivity call simply fails. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Profile Owner in this case MDM probably as it is creating work profile can configure CrossProfileIntentFilter that would allow cross profile intent resolution and once you start intent it will give option to user to select either main application or work profile application